# What could be the value of x that will satisfy $\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^x+\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)^x=2^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve the equation $\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^x+\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)^x=2^x$

I know the answer is 2 that is x=2 but it really hard for me to think how it came .please help me with step wise solution

Comment: If $x=2$ left is $(2\sqrt{2})^2+0^2=8$ but right is $2^2=4.$

Comment: UThis question is obviously faulty. $\sqrt 2 +\sqrt 2 = 2\sqrt 2$, no? And $\sqrt 2 -\sqrt 2=0$. So you're solving $$(2\sqrt2)^x=2^x$$ which requires $x=0$. But this in turn is wrong because $0^0\neq 0$

Comment: How does $x=2$ work?

Answer (score 3):

$$
\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2}\right)^x+\left(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}\right)^x=2^x\\
\left(2\sqrt{2}\right)^x+0^x=2^x,\ x>0\\
\left(2\sqrt{2}\right)^x=2^x\\
\left(2^{1+\frac{1}{2}}\right)^x=2^x\\
2^{\frac{3}{2}x}=2^x\\
\frac{3}{2}x=x\\
\frac{3}{2}=1.
$$

So, there are no x values that make the two sides of the equation true. $x=0$ is also not a solution because it leads to the expression $0^0$ [which is typically considered undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero). If we agree that $0^0=1$, then $x=0$ might be considred be a possible solution to the equation. This is easy to check: 
$$\left(2\sqrt{2}\right)^0+0^0=2^0\implies 1+1=1\implies 2=1.$$

That is obviously not a true statement. So, in that case, $x=0$ is not a solution either.

Also notice that I wrote $x>0$ because if we allow $x$ to take on negative values, we would be dividing by zero: $0^{-a}=\frac{1}{0^a}=\frac{1}{0}$ ($a>0$). All in all, the equation seems to have no solutions in real numbers.